# Example usage of Observable.GroupBy in F#

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I'm trying to determine how to make use of the group by function in Reactive Extensions.  Any chance someone has a simple example to illustrate it being used in F#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're most likely facing is that F#'s type inference is hard-pressed for lambdas when relating to `Func<T, T1...>`, `Action<T>` and such, especially in methods with multiple overloads.

If you're using Rx's API which was designed for idiomatic C#/VB, most of the time you'll end up having to annotate types to point the compiler in the right direction.

GroupBy in its simplest form takes in a key selector and produces an observable of groups. Each group has a key and is in itself an Observable which is a stream of values under that key.

In this example, we have two groups being formed: Even or Odd, so you get two `IGroupedObservable<string, int>` and `SelectMany` is used to recombine the groups.

Using the regular Rx methods:

```
let log message s = printfn "%s: %A" message s       

let disposable = 
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
              .Select(int)              
              .Do(log "Produced")
              .GroupBy(fun n -> if n % 2 = 0 then "Even" else "Odd")
              .SelectMany(fun (group : IGroupedObservable<string, int>) -> group.Select(fun i -> group.Key, i))          
              .Do(log "Kind")
              .Subscribe()
```

Which is pretty horrendous...

To make it more idiomatic, you'd need to augment the Observable module like so:

```
type Observable with
    static member log message o = Observable.Do(o, log message)
    static member groupBy selector o = Observable.GroupBy(o, (fun v -> selector(v)))
    static member collect (selector : 'a -> IObservable<'b>) o = Observable.SelectMany(o, selector)
```

Now you can express the same code above as:

```
let disposable = 
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
    |> Observable.map int
    |> Observable.log "Produced"
    |> Observable.groupBy (fun n -> if n % 2 = 0 then "Even" else "Odd")
    |> Observable.collect(fun group -> group |> Observable.map(fun i -> group.Key, i))                  
    |> Observable.log "Kind"
    |> Observable.subscribe(fun _ -> ())
```

...which is much more readable and needs no annotations.

Output:

```
Produced: 0
Kind: ("Even", 0)
Produced: 1
Kind: ("Odd", 1)
Produced: 2
Kind: ("Even", 2)
Produced: 3
Kind: ("Odd", 3)
```

Comment: F# type inference also deals better with the pipeline style than with the fluent style.